# How can I grant Team Project access to all users?

Tags: security, tfs

In our organization we have some projects which are (by policy) open to all developers, QA, and project managers who have access to TFS. In a team project collection with more than 150 team projects and 500+ valid users, how can we easily add all valid TFS users to the "Readers" group for one specific project?

Considerations:

- `[Global]\Project Collection Valid Users` cannot be added to any group, because every group is automatically a member of the Valid Users group. That would create a circular membership, and TFS won't let you do it (as far as I have learned through experimentation) anyway.
- We could create a new AD or TFS group to contain a custom list of "valid users," but that list is constantly changing in an organization this size, and it would present a management challenge trying to keep that list in sync. I would rather find a way to take advantage of the fact that TFS already "knows" who all the valid users are.

I have already looked at the StackOverflow questions [How to Grant Read-Only Access to All TFS Team Projects to a Group of Users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889389/how-to-add-windows-group-as-readers-to-all-projects-in-tfs-2010-collection) and [How to add Windows group as “Readers” to all projects in TFS 2010 collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961727/how-to-grant-read-only-access-to-all-tfs-team-projects-to-a-group-of-users) which were suggested as I began typing this question, but I am not trying to add **one user** to **all projects**; I am trying to add **all users** to **one project**.

Comment: Ultimately users will be defined in *some* list... how would TFS know if the list has changed without nobody maintaining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you cannot add `Project Collection Valid Users` to a project group, you can add the group itself and give it the same permissions as another group (for example, the project's `Readers` group).

### Steps to Add "Project Collection Valid Users" to a Team Project

In this example, we will grant read-only access to all valid users in the collection. You will probably want to grant matching access to the project's source code as well, so I will include that in the example.

1. Open Team Explorer
2. Right-click on the team project name
3. Select **Security...**
4. In the Project Security dialog that opens, make sure that **Team Foundation Server Group** is selected, and click **Add...**
5. In the Add Group dialog that opens, your project's groups and all global groups are listed. Select `[YourCollectionName]\Project Collection Valid Users` and click **OK**.
6. Back in the Project Security dialog, the lower pane lists available permissions. Check the **view project-level information** permission.

   - Optionally, select the **View test runs** permission as well, since that's what the `Readers` group has by default.
7. Click **Close** to close the Project Security dialog.
8. Open Source Control Explorer
9. Right-click on the source control root for your project
10. Select **Properties..._**
11. Click the **Security** tab in the Properties dialog
12. Make sure that **Team Foundation Server Group** is selected, and click **Add...**
    selected, and click **Add...**
13. In the Add Group dialog that opens, your project's groups and all global groups are listed. Select `[YourCollectionName]\Project Collection Valid Users` and click **OK**.
14. Back in the Properties dialog, still on the **Security** tab, the lower pane lists available permissions. Check **Allow** for the **Read** permission.

Now all users who have been added to any team project in your TFS Project Collection will be able to access your project and view source code.

Comment: In TFS 2012, this doesn't seem to work anymore: I can't add an existing group to a project. If anyone has a solution, I am very interested.